# How to pass data from one view to another view controller in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, shake

I am using **Xcode 4.3.1**. I have created the UI using Storyboard which has many View Controllers.

**Issue**

In my app i am using ShakeGesture. While shaking i am doing some operations, its working fine. But, when shaking get stopped i need to pass some values to another View controller to display it. I have seen many post it says how to pass value when button clicked,but no one related with my problem.

It would be great if you solve my issue

**My question is**

How to pass values from one View to another View controller after shaking get stopped?

I am looking for any examples or tutorials. Much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Exact function for the above question

I am having an button in **First View Controller**

[image]

When the button triggered it will popup pickerview with some datas. When the user selects it the picker value replaces the button value.

[image]

Then Shaking happens when it stopped i have to pass the data to other view controller.

**Code**

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
{
        // I need to pass data here. Thats i am confusing

}
```

}

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a segue by ctrl dragging from the first view controller to the second one in the storyboard. Click on the segue and go to the identity inspector (press command-option-3). In the identifier field give it a name, say "Shaking Stopped". Then in your motion ended method use...

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Shaking Stopped" sender:self];
```

This will make the view switch to your second one. Then in your prepare for segue change it to this...(of course using your own values)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Shaking Stopped"]) {
<The Second View Controller> *controller = segue.destinationViewController
        //change your values in the other view controller here 
        controller.someValue = self.someValue //an example
```

Comment: If a segue to the new view controller is getting performed when the shaking stops then yes, if not, it will not get called. You can put the lines after the `if` statement in any method you want (possibly a method that gets called when shaking is stopped)

Comment: I modified my answer. Let me know if that helps

Comment: yes thats the perfect answer which i got from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792567/how-to-pass-data-from-one-view-to-other-view-in-ios).. it helps +1 for your support.. do you know how to add data to that

Answer (score 0):

to detect the end of the shake gesture, implement motionEnded:withEvent in your view controller.

```
- (void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
 {
   // perform the seque
 }
}
```

using techniques described above for passing data to this view controller

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. you commented the perform the seque.. I am having problem over there.. I haven't got any clue about performing the seque inside the method.. could you update that please