# How to pass data from one View to other view in IOS using UIStoryboard segues?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uistoryboard, shake

I am using **Xcode 4.3.1**. I have created the UI using Storyboard which has many View Controllers.

**Issue**

In my app i am using ShakeGesture. While shaking i am doing some operations, its working fine. But, when shaking get stopped i need to pass some values to another View controller to display it. I have seen many post it says how to pass value when button clicked,but no one related with my problem.

It would be great if you solve my issue

**My question is**

How to pass values from one View to another View controller after shaking get stopped?

I am looking for any examples or tutorials. Much appreciated.

Exact function for the above question

I am having an button in **First View Controller**

[image]

When the button triggered it will popup pickerview with some datas. When the user selects it the picker value replaces the button value.

[image]

Then Shaking happens when it stopped i have to pass the data to other view controller.

**Code**

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
{
        // I need to pass data here. Thats i am confusing

}
```

}

This question was asked before but i couldn't get the solution thats why i am asking again. Apologise for that.
Thanks for your help guys

Comment: How about using **protocols**? That's exactly what you need to implement.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11708506/530432

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052594/xcode-update-viewcontroller-label-text-from-different-view/10052641#10052641) please. I have explained how to implement protocol.

Comment: thanks for your comments i will have a look at it guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data from one view to another view controller in IOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785092/how-to-pass-data-from-one-view-to-another-view-controller-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the data explicitly and in storyboard that is with the prepareForSegue call.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ContactsViewControllerSegue"]){
        ContactsViewController *cvc = (ContactsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        cvc.contacts = self.contacts;
        cvc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

For a full tutorial check out this [website](http://photoplyr.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/ios-5-storyboard-how-to-use-segues-scenes-and-static-content-uitableviews/).

To programmatically trigger the segue you can check the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html), but here is their example on orientation change.

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayAlternateView" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
// remainder of example omitted....
}
```

So you will trigger the segue when shaking stops, and then prepare the next viewController in the prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. i am just confused how prepare for segue is called when the shake stopped..

Comment: I have added the code sample for triggering a segue programmatically.

Comment: and cam did you have any idea about sending data with that segue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create string object in SecondViewController and set Property(nonatomic,retain) and synthesize it and after below code add when you push controller.

```
SecondViewController *objSecondViewController=[[SecondViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];             

objSecondViewController.strtitle=@"Your data";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondViewController animated:YES];
[objSecondViewController release];
```

Comment: I tired in this way but it causing exception